# How to remove index.php from url in codeigniter by using codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess

I am having a problem that I want to remove index.php from my url
My url is like http://localhost/Houseboat/index.php/home/about
is want to  change into http://localhost/Houseboat/home/about

please help me to solve my problem

Comment: I put this code RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: I put this code #RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: But its not working..the error is that the url is not in the server when i removed index.php

Answer (score 1):

First you need to access your .htaccess file it should be in public_html or a folder within that. If it's not you need to create it then copy and paste the following code into that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Hope this helps